# Symfony2 - Testing Doctrine Listener

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, phpunit

I've created a listener on doctrine event (persist, update & remove) that save in remote DB all actions (pattern : **who do what, when, old value, new value**).

It works.

In order to have continuous integration I wrote some unit tests by retrieving these logs after each action.

```
/**
 * @param $uid      user id
 * @param $isValid  is user need to be added 
 */
public function testGetLogs($uid, $isValid) {

    $um = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('user_manager');

    /** @var EntityManager $em */
    $em = $this->doctrine->getManager();
    $referentielUser = $um->getReferentielUser($uid);

    // Lazy method to retrieve application's identifiers
    $auditDummy = new AuditEntry();
    $dir = $auditDummy->getAppDir();
    $host = $auditDummy->getAppHost();

    if (false !== $referentielUser) {
        $user = $referentielUser->toUser();
        // add the user
        $valid = $um->addUser($user);
    } else {
        $valid = false;
    }

    $this->assertEquals($isValid, $valid);

    if ($valid) {
        // find latest logs for insertion
        $logs = array_reverse($this->doctrineListener->getLogs(array('appdir'=>$dir, 'apphost'=>$host)));
        $this->logTesting($logs[0], 'insert');

        // edit the user
        $user->setLocked(true);
        $em->commit();

        // find latest logs for edition
        $logs = array_reverse($this->doctrineListener->getLogs(array('appdir'=>$dir, 'apphost'=>$host)));
        $this->logTesting($logs[0], 'update');

        // remove the user
        $em->remove($user);
        $em->commit();

        // find latest logs for removal
        $logs = array_reverse($this->doctrineListener->getLogs(array('appdir'=>$dir, 'apphost'=>$host)));
        $this->logTesting($logs[0], 'delete');

    }

}

private function logTesting($log, $type) {
    $this->assertEquals(/* Folder */, $log['APPDIR']);
    $this->assertEquals('cli', $log['IP']);
    $this->assertEquals(/* Table */, $log['TARGETTABLE']);
    $this->assertEquals(strtoupper($type), $log['ACTION']);

    $dateLog = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $log['DATETIME']);
    $diff = $dateLog->diff(new \DateTime());
    $this->assertLessThan(5, $diff->s);
}
```

User is correctly added but is not edited nor removed.
Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$em->flush()` to make Doctrine execute queries to database, not `$em->commit`.

Comment: And can I use two flushes in a row ?

    $user->setEnabled(false);
    $em->flush();
    
    $em->remove($user);
    $em->flush();

Comment: Sure, you can call `flush` method as many times, as you need - it will write to database changes you've done to the moment.

Comment: I used `flush`  as you said but it didn't pass through `$this->logTesting()` method, so i had to rewrite it in the `testGetLog` method's body.